# Server name resolution messed up when running PiHole in Docker

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, docker

Yesterday I installed PiHole as a Docker container on my home server along with several other containers. While the ad blocking works fine after some adjustments, I also had to disable the dnsmasq and systemd/resolved as per the docs. This caused my home server to lose all name resolution but if I didn't do this the PiHole container complained about the host port 53 being locked and wouldn't start.

How can I enable name resolution outside Docker on my server while still running the PiHole container for other network devices?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Server with a static IP in the 192.168.1.0/24 range.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have my routers DHCP point all devices on the network to use my PiHole as DNS.
The PiHole lives in a Docker container on one of the machines running Ubuntu 18.10 on the network.

I have had to have that machine ignore the DNS coming from the DHCP and instead have the Ubuntu machine use the name servers of my ISP (below I will use `1.1.1.1` and `8.8.8.8` just as an example).

I am running NetworkManager, so have had to change `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` by setting `dns=none` under `[main]`.

For the part of ignoring the DHCP given name servers, change: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and add:

`supersede domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8;`

Furthermore, I've updated `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/base` by setting `nameserver 1.1.1.1`

I also stopped and disabled `dnsmsq` to avoid any conflict on port 53 when I start Pi-hole running:
`sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq` and `sudo systemctl disable dnsmasq`

Last, but not least, make sure that you start your Pi-hole container with arguments for DNS, the name servers to forward to, (environment variables DNS1 and DNS2) as well as setting the IP of the container (otherwise it will try to bind to `127.0.0.1:53`) by specifying:

`-p 192.168.1.10:53:53/tcp -p 192.168.1.10:53:53/udp`

if `192.168.1.10` is the IP of the machine running the Pi-hole container.

Hope something here helped.